# json_value function like how to create method in java

Tags: java, sql

I don't know whether it is possible or not but
I  have requirement like method to do the same functionality like in sql query json_value('','') does.

how to approach same like functionality through java method.

**for example like this**

```
public class MyCustomSQLFunction {
    
    public static String Custom_Json_Value(String json,String fieldName) {
        // to do here
        
    }
}
```

Any help is very appriciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think JsonPointer will help in your case.

```
public class MyCustomSQLFunction {
    
    public static String Custom_Json_Value(String json,String fieldName) {
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json));
        JsonStructure jsonStructure = reader.read();
        reader.close();
        JsonPointer jsonPointer = Json.createPointer(fieldName);
        String value = (String)jsonPointer.getValue(jsonStructure);
        return value;
    }
}
```

click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/json-pointer) for more details.